# Project elements of List as properties of anonymous object

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of enums that I need to convert to an anonymous object with a property for each enum.

For example:

```
public enum MyColors
{
    Red,
    Blue,
    Green,
}
```

What I need is

```
new { MyColors.Red, MyColors.Blue}
```

I have a List

```
var colorList = new List<MyColors> {MyColors.Red, MyColors.Blue};
```

There a shorthand way of creating an anonymous object with every element in my list as a property?

Not looking for ExpandoObject

Comment: Not really, but why do you need an anonymous object of enums?

Comment: Can you describe the desired behaviour of this anonymous object? Do you mean you want an `obj` where `obj.Red` evaluates to `MyColors.Red` and `obj.Blue` evaluates to `MyColors.Blue`? Why not just use `MyColors` then?

Comment: Think the closest you get is something like `new { Red = MyColors.Red, Blue = MyColors.Blue }`

Comment: If you need an actual array of the values, there's always [Enum.GetValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Anonymous objects need to be compiled. Their fields cant be created dynamically like this, the *runtime* would not know what to do with them, also you wouldn't be able to write code to use the properties

Comment: I need an anonymous object to use with a diff library that's expecting it.... I only want certain enums available (Red & Blue) and I wanted to reuse some existing logic returning the filtered list above...

Comment: `new { MyColors.Red, MyColors.Blue}`

Comment: Enum.GetValues won't work - 1. I'm not looking for an array of values. 2. I only want certain values of the Enum

Comment: @TheGeneral - yeah, that's what I have now - I was just looking for a neater way to reuse some existing logic that's returning the list of colors I want as a list

Comment: please elaborate what diff library does and how it uses this object? is this something related to serialization? You can construct types in the runtime using [Emit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit?view=netframework-4.8) but this will not be a 'shorthand' :)

Comment: maybe you are looking for ExpandoObject.

Comment: perhaps that would work. Thank you. Definitely not a duplicate with the ExpandoObject question that Peter Dunhio pasted.... but I guess he finds pleasure in marking questions as dupes